# Golang MySQL Scan only populate results if all fields passed

Tags: go

Golang mysql `row.Scan(&pointerAddress)` not populating fields.

Showing me this when i send request so omitempty does work.

If I fill all User struct fields to `row.Scan(&user.Email, etc...)` only then show values in result.

[image]

Code :

```
type User struct{
    Id int `json:"id"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname string `json:"lastname"`
    RememberToken string `json:"remember_token"`
    Phone int64 `json:"phone"`
    AgreeTerms int8 `json:"agree_terms"`
    AllowPromotionalOffers int8 `json:"allow_promotional_offers"`
    CreatedAt string `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt string `json:"updated_at"`
    LandlordId int64 `json:"landlord_id"`
    RenterId int64 `json:"renter_id"`
}
```

My Login Function :

```
func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := models.User{}

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    row, err := database.DB.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?", user.Email)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%w", err)
    }

    defer row.Close()

    for row.Next() {
        err = row.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Email, &user.Password)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("%w", err)
        }
    }

    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%w", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `,omitempty` in the `json` tags. Note that this has 0 to do with SQL and row scanning. In Go, when you initialize a struct, *all* of its fields are initialized to their type's zero value, and just because they are not set explicitly does not mean they don't exist, they *are* there. There is no "undefined" field in Go.

Comment: Thanks, it changed the json response but ```row.Scan(&user.Id)``` showing empty, mean not showing result.

Comment: I am not certain what you mean by that comment. Please try explaining in more detail what the new problem is. Edit the question and add the new code, new input, and new output.

Comment: Note that `database/sql` provides only the basic SQL stuff. If you use `SELECT * FROM ...` you have to pass all fields, in the correct order, **manually**. If you use `SELECT id, email, first_name, last_name FROM ...` then you have to pass the corresponding 4 fields to `Scan` **manually**. There's is way around it with the standard library. If you don't want to do that you have to use some library that will do it for you, like sqlx, or some other such ORM like stuff.

Comment: @mkopriva okay, yes that's the problem i think - i have to pass all fields in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your struct inside the for statement, if your resultset is a **query rows** (maybe a slices of structs):

```
var users []*models.User
for row.Next() {
    user := new(models.User)
    err = row.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Email, &user.Password)
    users = append(users, user)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Errorf("%w", err)
    }
}
......
```

You don't need to loop if you're using a QueryRow resultSet

```
    row, err := database.DB.QueryRow("SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email=?", 
    user.Email).Scan(&user.Id, &user.Email, &user.Password)
```

As the best practice, you should avoid using "*" if not essential. ;)
It's a little verbose but it works.